# Error al instalar babel

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Despues de instalar node al usar el comando

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env
```

me sale este error

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${APPDATA}
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:415:13
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at envReplace (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:411:12)
    at parseField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:389:7)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:330:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:328:23)
    at ConfigChain.addString (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:316:10)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13)
    at Conf.f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at Conf.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:335:10)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:494:27)
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${APPDATA}
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:415:13
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at envReplace (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:411:12)
    at parseField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:389:7)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:330:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:328:23)
    at ConfigChain.addString (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:316:10)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13)
    at Conf.f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at Conf.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:335:10)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:494:27)
```

que puedo hacer? ya reinstale node 3 veces.

al hacer un `npm config get registry` me sale el mismo error

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un `npm config get registry` a ver que te devuelve?

Comment: @MauricioContreras al hacerlo me salta el mismo error

Comment: Recuerda ejecutar estos comandos con privilegios de administrador (por lo que veo usas Windows) para que puedas escribir en carpetas de sistema

Comment: no importa si ejecuto el cmd o el comand prompt de node como administador me da los mismos errores, pero al poner el comando npm config get registry me sale en el de node "npm should be run outside of node rpl, in your normal shell" y la verdad no se como hacer que el npm funcione en el cmd

Answer (score -1):

Creaste el package.json antes de instalar los paquetes de babel? recuerda que se instalan como dependecias de desarrollo y se sitúan en el mismo package.json

El package.json se crea asi:

```
npm init -y
```